# Error Code 401 while using Server Side Huawei Mobile Service API for app level access token

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-iap, huawei-account

From yesterday I am facing this error code 401 while accessing token from server using this API: https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token

Just for your information I am using Postman. Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this is of interest https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/38054564 (app id and flow control)

Answer (score 1):

Error 401 usually means “unauthorized” or “request denied” because a request lacks valid credential. Although this error code is not listed in Account Kit server api, a developer can find it in other kit document - https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/webapi-error-code-0000001050163432-V5. Basically, a developer need to make sure that their API key and/or token is valid.

Answer (score 0):

while using huawei auth service if error code 401 returned it means access token becomes invalid and we need to obtain a new token. Token Validity is 60 mins.